# Invalid Operation Exception in Ninject: "Error loading Ninject component IAdviceRegistry "

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-extensions, ninject-interception

I am using Ninject 3.2.0.0 with Ninject.Extension.Factory 3.2.0.0 in a webforms application.

I am getting error reports of the following...

Error loading Ninject component IAdviceRegistry
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Suggestions:
  1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly
     implemented the AddComponents() method.
  2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.

at Ninject.Components.ComponentContainer.Get(Type component) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Components\ComponentContainer.cs:line 162
   at Ninject.Components.ComponentContainer.GetT in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Components\ComponentContainer.cs:line 116
   at Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Activation.Strategies.ProxyActivationStrategy.ShouldProxy(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.interception\src\Ninject.Extensions.Interception\Activation\Strategies\ProxyActivationStrategy.cs:line 66
   at Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Activation.Strategies.ProxyActivationStrategy.Deactivate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.interception\src\Ninject.Extensions.Interception\Activation\Strategies\ProxyActivationStrategy.cs:line 51
   at Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__4(IActivationStrategy s) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Pipeline.cs:line 72
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:line 31
   at Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.Deactivate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Pipeline.cs:line 74
   at Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Forget(CacheEntry entry) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:line 254
   at Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Forget(IEnumerable`1 cacheEntries) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:line 240
   at Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Clear(Object scope) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:line 198
   at Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__1(Object o, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:line 94
   at Ninject.Activation.Blocks.ActivationBlock.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Blocks\ActivationBlock.cs:line 59
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Disposal.DisposableObject.Dispose() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Disposal\DisposableObject.cs:line 33
   at Brightspot.WebApi.Ioc.NinjectDependencyScope.Dispose()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.DisposeRequestResources(HttpRequestMessage request)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extensions

- ninject.extensions.interception
- Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy

*or* the extensions

- ninject.extensions.interception
- Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu

are present.

EDIT:

The registration of the `IAdviceRegistry` is part of the `InterceptionModule` of the ninject.extensions.interception extension.

So the extension is not loaded properly.
This is either because the extension dll was not properly copied to the output path / deployment path or (most likely issue) or you have configured the kernel to not autoload extensions / not do it correctly.

If you're using the `StandardKernel` without modifying any settings you should be good. However changing `INinjectSettings.LoadExtensions = false` or changing `INinjectSettings.ExtensionSearchPatterns` can break things.

Comment: I checked it out. But still the issue came

Comment: What did you exactly check out? Is the extension dll copied to the same path as the exe is executed from? Is this the same as the execution path (like "start in" of a shortcut)? is extension loading enabled?

Comment: Could you try to do `IKernel.Load<InterceptionModule>()`?

Comment: So you are probably injecting a factory before loading the InterceptionModule. You or some code is...
btw. You need to be way more specific about what you do and so on if you want to really get some help.

Comment: StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings()
            {
                LoadExtensions = false,
            });

            this.Kernel.Load(new[] { new FuncModule() });
            this.Kernel.Bind<InterceptionModule>().ToSelf();
            this.Kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EFRepository<>));
            this.Kernel.Bind(typeof(IService<>)).To(typeof(Service<>));
            this.Kernel.Bind<IApproveContextFactory>().ToFactory();

Comment: uhm there's a lot of errors in that. First, **don't** set `LoadExtensions = false`. Second, **don`t** `.Bind<InterceptionModule>()`. That's totally useless. You *may* try `.Load<InterceptionModule()`, but when `LoadExtensions = true`, it it will lead to problems (same component registered multiple times).

Comment: If I load this kernel.Load<InterceptionModule>(); I get the this issue Error 2 'Ninject.Extensions.Interception.InterceptionModule' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TModule' in the generic type or method 'Ninject.ModuleLoadExtensions.Load<TModule>(Ninject.IKernel)

Comment: **Remove** any code pertaining `InterceptionModule`. **Change** `LoadExtensions = false` to `LoadExtensions = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that issue.If we use factory pattern load the functional module in ninject. The functional module not loaded properly while using factory pattern. So you need to load the functional module in ninject.. And access the factory class using standard kernel...

```
this.Kernel.Load(new[] { new FuncModule() });
StandardKernel.Get<IApproveContextFactory>()
```